# UITextView not resizing along woth keyboard showing

Tags: iphone, keyboard, resize, uitextview

I have a text view (nib-file) with a UITextView maximised the entire view.

When ever i push the viewcontroller on to the navigationcontroller i load the keyboard in the text view's viewDidLoad method.

My problem is that when i write text that has more lines than there is space for, the text is behind the keyboard. I followed the sampe from Apple [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/KeyboardAccessory/Listings/Classes_ViewController_m.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009462-Classes_ViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6).

If i log the "newTextViewFrame" it's NULL. but if i debug the thing it has a fine value.
Even if i hardcode it, the UITextView doesent change size.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {

/*
 Reduce the size of the text view so that it's not obscured by the keyboard.
 Animate the resize so that it's in sync with the appearance of the keyboard.
 */

NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];

// Get the origin of the keyboard when it's displayed.
NSValue* aValue = [userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];

// Get the top of the keyboard as the y coordinate of its origin in self's view's coordinate system. The bottom of the text view's frame should align with the top of the keyboard's final position.
CGRect keyboardRect = [aValue CGRectValue];
keyboardRect = [self.view convertRect:keyboardRect fromView:nil];

CGFloat keyboardTop = keyboardRect.origin.y;
CGRect newTextViewFrame = self.view.bounds;
newTextViewFrame.size.height = keyboardTop; - (self.view.bounds.origin.y);

// Get the duration of the animation.
NSValue *animationDurationValue = [userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
[animationDurationValue getValue:&animationDuration];

// Animate the resize of the text view's frame in sync with the keyboard's appearance.
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];

createListingTextView.frame = newTextViewFrame;

[UIView commitAnimations];
NSLog(@"Textview resized: %@", newTextViewFrame);
```

}

My task i simple: Implement a View with a UITextView and the keyboard open and scroll the UITextView when ever the text exceeds.

Please advice...

Answer (score 1):

There is a semi-colon after keyboardTop on the line

```
newTextViewFrame.size.height = keyboardTop; - (self.view.bounds.origin.y);
```

This would certainly prevent newTextViewFrame from getting the adjusted height.

Comment: Woops. My mistake. I put the semi-colon there for som test purpose. The problem still persists. It seems like the UITextView i somehow redrawed wthout my settings. Even if i decrease the size in IB, the UITextView is maximized when the View i showing.

Comment: Odd. Have to ask the obvious: are you sure you're changing the right nib file? Have you tried a clean and rebuild?

Comment: Yeah.. I've actually tried copy-pasting the example from Apple, and still cant make it resize. Even if I set the size of the TextArea to a vary small in the designer, the area is "maximized" when running the app. I this the code above should work, but I'm missing something that maximizes the area at runtime. I will drop the entire code when i get home from work.